# How can I monitor changes to IIS when neither FileSystemWatcher nor IIS-Configuration event log will report on System32 changes?

Tags: iis

We have to monitor changes to IIS 8.5 on 2012 R2

```
The FileSystemWatcher Windows service I wrote works on anything except System32 subdirectories,
 despite System having permissions on the inetsrv\config folder (cannot get Read permission on anything higher), and
 The OOTB IIS-Configuration event log won't report manual changes to inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config 
      (e.g. via Notepad++).
```

Doesn't make a difference where the FSW Windows service is installed. And IIS takes applicationHost.config changes immediately, without restart.

The business case is that Security said so. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can Monitor IIS Configuration Changes using SAM via event logs by ensuring that you enable the EVENT LOGS first for IIS Configuration changes:

Enable the IIS configuration change to be written on Event Logs

1. Go to Start > Event Viewer.
2. Expand Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > IIS-Configuration > Operational > Enable Log.
3. Close Event Viewer to Finish.

Then you may now IMPORT the attached SAM Templates and create a component monitor alert so you will know which IIS Configuration has been changed.

[How to Monitor IIS Configuration change using Event Logs in SAM](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/product-forums/server-application-monitor-sam/f/forum/15259/how-to-monitor-iis-configuration-change-using-event-logs-in-sam).